# Proving that $\vec F$ is conservative field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vector-fields, conservative-field

> I need to prove that $\vec F$ is coservative field:

$$\vec F=\underbrace{\bigg(yz+\frac{1}{yz} \bigg)}_{Q} \hat i+\underbrace{\bigg(xz-\frac{x}{y^2z} \bigg)}_{P}\hat j+\underbrace{\bigg(xy-\frac{x}{yz^2} \bigg)}_R\hat k$$

**My attempt:**

$\vec F$ is conservative field iff $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial R}{\partial z}$

but $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} \neq \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}$

Comment: A field is conservative if its _curl_ is zero.  Check your formula for the curl;  it's nothing like what you've written here.

Comment: What is the curl in that case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement about whether $\vec{F}$ is a conservative field is wrong.  $\vec{F}$ is conservative iff $\nabla \times \vec{F} = 0$.  In terms of the Cartesian components, the curl is
$$
\nabla \times \vec{F} = \left( \frac{\partial R}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial z} \right) \hat{x} + \left( \frac{\partial Q}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial R}{\partial x} \right) \hat{y} + \left( \frac{\partial P}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial Q}{\partial y} \right) \hat{z}.
$$
Note that all three components have to vanish for the curl to be zero.

Alternately, you can try to find a scalar field $\phi(x,y,z)$ such that $\vec{F} = \nabla \phi$.  (It's actually not too hard to do this by inspection, in this particular case.)  It is generally true that the curl of $\vec{F}$ will be zero if it can be expressed as the gradient of a scalar field.  The converse is also true, so long as the fields are defined everywhere in space (more or less.)